# Why are user links stackoverflow.com/users/:id/:username

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I'm assuming that `stackoverflow.com/users/:id/:username` is the format of the user profile URL.  Perhaps the number is not the user's ID, but some other piece of information.

Regardless, does a `username` not uniquely identify a profile?  What is the purpose of the extra number?

If the `username` is uniquely identifying, could `stackoverflow.com/users/:username` also point to the user's profile?  This would be a much more visually appealing solution.

Comment: Usernames aren't unique - [example](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=bob) - the id is what makes a user unique.

Comment: [Poor Alex](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382188)

Comment: @bluefeet - a lot of bobs :)

Comment: @rene - lol popular name!

Comment: That awkward moment when my old username was unique and current one isn't

Comment: The last part is a [slug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/47427/880772): not-unique, optional, and there to make the link human-readable.

Comment: There are even [three bluefeets](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=bluefeet) but only [one meagar](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=meagar).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Perhaps the number is not the user's ID, but some other piece of
>   information.

No, it's the user's ID.

> Regardless, does a username not uniquely identify a profile?

No, it doesn't - more than one user can adopt the same name (as in real life).

> What is the purpose of the extra number?

To uniquely identify a profile! Note that the username is effectively ignored when resolving the profile page by clicking on:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/definitelynotjonrsharpe

Comment: You should definitely change your username to `definitelynotjonrsharpe`.

Comment: @theB that would only confuse people, I think!

Comment: Provided that Stack Overflow has a distributed DB, how do they generate the user's ID so that it is sequential and unique at any point in time? In case they use a centralized service, isn't this service subject to a heavy load when multiple users register themselves at the same time all over the world?

Comment: @tonix I don't know, I don't work there. Nick Craver has posted some stuff on the SO architectures, see e.g. https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/.

Comment: OK, I will check it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> Regardless, does a username not uniquely identify a profile? What is the purpose of the extra number?

No the username doesn't uniquely identify a profile. Stack Exchange allows exact duplicates of usernames.

What identifies your profile uniquely is the number actually.